# left and right aligned section title on one line

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I am trying to have a simple bilingual title for a section.  The English text should align to the left and the Arabic text should align to the right, both on the same line.

The following line of code almost does the job, but the Arabic text is not fully right aligned——it looks like there is an extra margin, compared to the rest of the document.

```
\section{English Title \hfill\textarabic{كلمة}}
```

I tried `titlesec`'s `block` shape, but that didn't do the trick.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Arabic Typesetting}    
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
    [block]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\rlap{\thesection}}{0em}
    {\hspace{.05\linewidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth}}[\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}    
\section{A section in English \hfill \textarabic{فصل باللغة العربية}}
\lipsum[1]    
\section{English Title \hfill \textarabic{عنوان بالعربي}}
\lipsum[2]    
\end{document}
```

You can use a `minipage` inside your section title to perform whatever alignment you need. Of course `titlesec` is essential in this situation. The `block` shape can be defined as this:

```
\titleformat{\section}
        [block]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\rlap{\thesection}}{0em}
        {\hspace{.05\linewidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{.95\textwidth}}[\end{minipage}]
```

where we left `.05\linewidth` for section numbering and the remaining `.95\textwidth` for the bilingual title.